# How to articulate this expression

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

[image]

I was walking a student through the binomial expansion process and remarked that I prefer Pascal's triangle to generate the coefficients.

He also needed to know this way of producing the numbers. The math itself isn't the issue, I don't know how to pronounce this. Khan calls the first part "N choose K." Is this the way to refer to this? (Yes, I know factorial, it's just the first part of the equation I want to be clear on.)

For what it's worth, I know why Khan uses his wording, thus my probability tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"N choose K" is a perfectly good way to express this.

In fact, MathJax renders

```
${n \choose k}$
```

as ${n \choose k}$.

A wordier way: "The number of combinations of $n$ things, taken $k$ at a time."

Comment: Thanks, John! I'd rather ask here to be sure than to mis-speak to these high schoolers.